# jQuery / Ajax to get html and save with php

Tags: php, jquery, function

I am trying to get a jQuery script to run behind the scenes with php. It basically will get the contents of a div with jQuery (works) then calls a script with ajax (works) but I need the ajax script that called the php to send the vars to php so I can save the conents.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( ".tweets" ).click(function() {
var htmlString = $( this ).html();
tweetUpdate(htmlString);
});

});
</script>

<script>
function tweetUpdate(htmlString)
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'saveTweets.php',
    data: htmlString,
    success: function (data) {
        // this is executed when ajax call finished well
        alert('content of the executed page: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
    }
});
}
</script>
```

and my code for saveTweets.php

```
<?
// SUPPOSED TO receive html conents called htmlString taken from a div
// and then I will write this code to a file with php and save it.  
echo $_POST[htmlString];

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give a name to the parameter, so that PHP can retrieve it. Change the `$.ajax` call to do:

```
data: { htmlString: htmlString },
```

Then in your PHP, you can reference `$_POST['htmlString']` to get the parameter.

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Thank you @Barmar. I will mark correct in 10 minutes when I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct your funcion.

```
  function tweetUpdate(htmlString)
    {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'saveTweets.php',
        data: "htmlString="+htmlString,
        success: function (data) {
            // this is executed when ajax call finished well
            alert('content of the executed page: ' + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // executed if something went wrong during call
            if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
        }
    });
    }
```

then on saveTweets.php page write below line, you will get value on that page.

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_REQUEST );echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  **json** is better for sending data:

```
data_htlm=[];

data_html.push({"htmlString": htmlString});
 $.ajax(
   {

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "saveTweets.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(data_html),
      success: function(html) 
        { 
          console.log(html);
        }
   });
```

now with php you can just do this:

```
echo $_POST['htmlString'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.post` method to post to a PHP page and then retrieve the result from that page in a callback function.